# If $f\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}\right)=0$, with $z=h(x,y)$, then $x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> If $f\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}\right)=0$, with $z=h(x,y)$, then show that
>   $$x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$$

Can anyone help by solving it? It's the first time I have seen an exercise like this.

Comment: What is θ? Is it supposed to be a differentiation symbol?

Comment: Without explanation... **any explanation** ...is going to be hard to guess what you are talking about...

Comment: Please clarify your question or it may get closed.

Comment: It's the differential symbol.

Comment: Knowing the first two, I need to show the final one.

Comment: What are $f$ and $h$? I can find some specific functions where the conclusion is not valid

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. If this is the "first time" you have seen such a problem, then what is the source and context? For instance, if it's a textbook exercise, then what topic is under discussion? Edit your question to add details; comments are easily overlooked.

Comment: In particular, for almost any function $z = h(x, y)$ (e.g., $h(x, y) = x^2$) and for $f(u, v) = 0$ for all $u, v$, the hypotheses hold, but the conclusion fails.

Comment: So the exercise is wrong?

Comment: What is the source of this question?